# MinGw32 Compliation issue when static linking is required (ADOL-C links ColPack)

Tags: linker, mingw

I have a mathematical Library ([ADOL-C](https://projects.coin-or.org/ADOL-C)) that needs to link to an other library ([ColPack](http://www.cscapes.org/coloringpage/software.htm)) for some optional tasks.

I can compile them fine in Linux, and both ADOl-C or ColPack alone in windows, but when I try to compile ADOL-C with ColPack in windows (MinGW 32, ld 2.22) I have the following issue:

```
$ make
Making all in ADOL-C
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/tests/ADOL-C-2.3.0/ADOL-C'
[...]
  CC     int_reverse_s.lo
  CC     int_reverse_t.lo
  CXXLD  libadolc.la

*** Warning: This system can not link to static lib archive /usr/lib/libColPack.
la.
*** I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
*** you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have.
Creating library file: .libs/libadolc.dll.a
sparse/.libs/libsparse.a(sparsedrivers.o): In function `generate_seed_jac':
c:\tests\ADOL-C-2.3.0\ADOL-C\src\sparse/sparsedrivers.cpp:119: undefined referen
ce to `ColPack::BipartiteGraphPartialColoringInterface::BipartiteGraphPartialCol
oringInterface(int, ...)'

[...]
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [libadolc.la] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/c/tests/ADOL-C-2.3.0/ADOL-C/src'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I can't just provide the dynamic library as in MinGW, even if I configure ColPack with --enable-shared, I never got actually any shared library from its compilation, only libColPack.[a|la|lai] and ColPack.exe.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a little longer, until I solved the problem.

Download Colpack-1.0.8.tar.gz and tested it with the following environment

Msys / mingw 4.7.0.

As you said, you can not use it to create a shared lib.
After some time I have found a more complex solution. From this basis I've found a shorter way.

**short solution:**

open **configure**

line# ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*** change ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*** to __

```
7660        enable_dlopen=no      set it to yes
7663        enable_win32_dll=no   set it to yes
7673        enable_shared=no      set it to yes
7710        enable_static=yes     set it to no
7717        enable_static=yes     set it to no  
8721        enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no      set it to yes
11797       enable_shared_with_static_runtimes_CXX=no  set it to yes
```

save and run

```
./configure --disable-static --enable-shared
```

open **libtool**

line# ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*** change ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*** to __

```
5547        allow_undefined=yes   set it to no
5550        allow_undefined=yes   set it to no
```

save and run

```
make clean
make
```

in the **.lib** directory should now be following files.

```
ColPack.exe      .. 30.08.2012
libColPack.la    .. 30.08.2012
libColPack.lai   .. 30.08.2012
libColPack-0.dll .. 30.08.2012
libColPack.dll.a .. 30.08.2012
```

outtake from **libColPack-0.dll**

```
Export Table:
  Name:                          libColPack-0.dll
  Time Date Stamp:               0x503F3A43 (30.08.2012 11:02:43)
  Version:                       0.00
  Ordinal Base:                  1
  Number of Functions:           883
  Number of Names:               883

  Ordinal   Entry Point   Name
        1   0x000012FC    _Z10createArgsiPPKcRSt6vectorISsSaISsEE
        2   0x00011034    _Z10toFileBiPCSsSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEES1_St3mapISsbSt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsbEEE
        3   0x00001FB0    _Z11mm_is_validPc
        ........
```

outtake from **libColPack.la**

```
# libColPack.la - a libtool library file
# Generated by libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4 
#
# Please DO NOT delete this file!
# It is necessary for linking the library.

# The name that we can dlopen(3).
dlname='libColPack-0.dll'

# Names of this library.
library_names='libColPack.dll.a'

......
```

Hope that helps !

**NOTE:**

Have not tested "make install" !

**To have both static and dynamic:**

Move libColPack.la, libColPack.lai and libColPack.dll.a to another folder. We need them and they will be overwritten. Delete the file libColPack.la, a directory-level higher.

Change libtool file back to its original state (the 2 lines) .

Run "make"

You will have a new libColPack.a

Move libColPack.dll.a back to .libs

Merging the content of the two previously moved files with the new libColPack.la (.lai).

Copy also the updated libColPack.la a directory-level higher.

**The new mixdown file: libColPack.la**

```
# libColPack.la - a libtool library file
# Generated by libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4 
#
# Please DO NOT delete this file!
# It is necessary for linking the library.

# The name that we can dlopen(3).
dlname='libColPack-0.dll'

# Names of this library.
library_names='libColPack.dll.a'

....

# The name of the static archive.
old_library='libColPack.a'
....
```

With this trick you have both **static and dynamic libs**.

Comment: Thank you, tested and working. ADOL-C package dynamically links with ColPack. This means that the libColPacl-0.dll must be available to the final application too. A case-specific working alternative is to use the configures of ADOL-C 2.2.1. These are able to statically link ColPAck 1.0.8. One question: is it possible to automatize this, so that the final users doesn't need to play with libtool and the configure apply this behaviour only in mingw and only if shared libraries are actually requested?

Comment: Glad to help. Have a look at my answer: "To have both static and dynamic:"